# vagrant up issue

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I have a VM that is made with vagrant and chef. Last night my computer restarted unexpectedly while the VM was up and running . After that, when I try to vagrant up the VM I get: 
**Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.**

```
[default] VM already created. Booting if it's not already running...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Running any VM customizations...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] VM booted and ready for use!
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- v-root: /vagrant
[default] -- v-data: /vagrant
[default] -- v-csr-2: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-2/roles
[default] -- v-csc-1: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks
[default] Running provisioner: Vagrant::Provisioners::ChefSolo...
[default] Generating chef JSON and uploading...
[default] Running chef-solo...
stdin: is not a tty
[Tue, 10 Jul 2012 00:59:36 -0700] INFO: *** Chef 0.10.2 ***
[Tue, 10 Jul 2012 00:59:36 -0700] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["role[my-site]"] from JSON
[Tue, 10 Jul 2012 00:59:36 -0700] INFO: Run List is [role[my-site]]
[Tue, 10 Jul 2012 00:59:36 -0700] INFO: Run List expands to [memcached, my-site, my-site::vm]
[Tue, 10 Jul 2012 00:59:36 -0700] INFO: Starting Chef Run for lucid32
[Tue, 10 Jul 2012 00:59:37 -0700] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[Tue, 10 Jul 2012 00:59:37 -0700] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[Tue, 10 Jul 2012 00:59:37 -0700] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out
[Tue, 10 Jul 2012 00:59:37 -0700] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

**Later edit:**

*Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out*

```
Generated at Tue Jul 10 00:59:37 -0700 2012
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/my-site/recipes/default.rb:114:in `from_file'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/recipe_definition_dsl_core.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/recipe_definition_dsl_core.rb:69:in `method_missing'
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/my-site/recipes/default.rb:109:in `from_file'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:578:in `load_recipe'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:40:in `include_recipe'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:27:in `each'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:27:in `include_recipe'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/run_context.rb:72:in `load'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/run_context.rb:69:in `each'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/run_context.rb:69:in `load'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:195:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:159:in `run'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:192:in `run_application'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:183:in `loop'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:183:in `run_application'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/application.rb:66:in `run'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/chef-solo:25
/opt/ruby/bin/chef-solo:19:in `load'
/opt/ruby/bin/chef-solo:19
```

Any thoughts,

Thanks,
Radu

Comment: What's the stacktrace in `/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out` look like?

Comment: added it as a later edit

Comment: Did the Chef run previously complete without errors?
In line 114 of `my-site/recipes/default.rb`, you're probably accessing some node attribute that doesn't exist. Have a look at that line of code, do you recognize what object is nil there, and can you maye make it so it isn't nil?

Comment: until the unexpected restart it worked fine ...

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug in your Chef recipe itself. If you read the stacktrace you can see that the error is actually on line 114 of the default recipe in the `my-site` cookbook. The Ruby error you're seeing means that you're attempting to do something like `a[:foo]` where `a` is `nil`. Of course, you can't call `[]` on `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I figured out that the chef version that was running in my VM was too old (0.10.10).

You have to update it:

```
local$ vagrant ssh
vagrant$ gem install chef
```

and try again.

Comment: Run as root / with sudo. As user vagrant you get this error: "You don't have write permissions into the /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory"

Answer (score 0):

I received the errors:

```
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.

Error executing action `create` on resource 'mysql_service[default]'
```

I used the:

```
local$ vagrant ssh
vagrant$ gem install chef
```

After trying again, it all worked out perfect.